# Как вычислить позицию элемента "треугольного" массива?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, любой-язык

Дан "треугольный" массив произвольного размера: N

```
0. [0..N-1]
1. [0..N-2]
2. [0..N-3]
...
N-1. [0]
```

но все ячейки хранятся последовательно в одномерном массиве (пронумерованны слева направо сверху вниз), соответственно от 0 до N*(N+1)/2-1 получается такое "логическое" разделение на "строки". Т.е. если N = 4, то имеем

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8
9
```

Требуется, зная индекс элемента (i), вычислить его логическую строку... т.е. в данном случае, при переборе всех индексов по порядку получим

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2
3
```

Каким образом это сделать без использования циклов, рекурсий и составления дополнительных массивов смещений? т.е. за O(1)

[дополнено]

Получается следующее неравенство, которое нужно решить в целых числах:

[image: http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1549373792/render.png]

Comment: Ну как бы формула суммы арифметической прогрессии известна. Всего и делов - целочисленно решить квадратное неравенство. Для заданного i сумма от N до K должна быть меньше i, а до K+1 больше либо равна. Причём проще считать снизу, а не сверху.

Comment: я в ту сторону и думаю, ступор какой-то словил... видимо забывать стал элементарные вещи

Comment: @Akina неравенство я составил, вопрос обновил, но как это решается, тем более в целых числах, давно уже не помню

Comment: Мда... Переверни треугольник. Тогда границы - это обычная и стандартная последовательность 1-3-6-10-15-... (которую вообще можно захардкодить, кстати). Остаётся найти промежуток, в который попадает заданное i (ну вернее N*(N+1)/2-i - надо же и заданную позицию перевернуть) - тупо половинным делением. И потом полученную строку пересчитать в исходный неперевёрнутый вид.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Номер [треугольного числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)/проверка на треугольное число T<sub>n</sub> делается формулой

```
n = (sqrt(8 * x + 1) - 1) / 2
```

Это и есть требуемая вам формула (с округлением вниз) для линейного индекса `x`, разве что с необходимостью "перевернуть" нумерацию.

Для матрицы размера NxN диапазон линейных индексов `i` будет равен `[0, N*(N+1)/2)`. Для треугольника вашего вида сначала "переворачиваем" `i` внутри диапазона линейных индексов

```
i = N * (N + 1) / 2 - i - 1;
```

Затем применяем вышеприведенную формулу

```
y = (sqrt(8 * i + 1) - 1) / 2;
```

Затем "переворачиваем" результат по вертикали

```
y = N - y - 1;
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29e298a4d8d29bca

Comment: про треугольные числа статья, это очень в тему... а то я очередное колесо начал изобретать) Жаль что решение вышло из рамок целочисленных операций, наверное таки есть смысл тогда таблицу смещений предварительно просчитать

Comment: @Isaev, таблицу смещений? Тогда уж можно просто в цикле посчитать с той же линейной сложностью: `x = 0, r = 0; while (x < i) { x+=n-r; r++; }`

Comment: @Андрей NOP, да это мысли вслух... просто обращение к этому массиву потом миллионы раз происходят, я думал, если вычисления получатся достаточно простые, то ничего страшного, а раз всё не так просто, то проще вычислить 1 раз при старте, создать табличку смещений и обращаться потом через неё

Comment: @Isaev, почему бы и нет, скорее всего это будет эффективнее, чем считать индекс каждый раз