# Номер элемента в матрице

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры-данных

имеется некоторая матрица, в которой находятся натуральные числа.
Зная число, необходимо найти его координаты в матрице. Элементы размещены таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент я нашёл последовательность, которой соответствует номера по крайней верхней горизонтали (1, 3, 4, 10...):

```
a(n) = if n mod 2 == 0 then n*(n+1)/2, otherwise (n-1)*n/2 + 1.
```

И крайней левой вертикали (1, 2, 6, 7...):

```
a(n) = n*(n+1)/2 if n is odd, otherwise (n-1)*n/2 + 1.
```

Однако пока что не могу додуматься, как это применить.

К примеру, единица в данной матрице имеет координаты [0, 0], а 19 [2, 3] и так далее.

Comment: Посмотрите, на какой по счету диагонали находится число N. Далее в зависимости от четности номера диагонали вам нужно будет найти место N в данной диагонали.

Comment: А как определить номер диагонали для числа N?

Comment: Ну найдите закономерность, какие числа находятся на каждой диагонали: [1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 6], [7, 10]... и обобщите ее для произвольного номера диагонали K. После этого вам всего лишь нужно будет решить неравенство Left(K) <= N <= Right(K)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользуясь [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/941078/281034), [этим](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1417583/520967) и [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23320333/9210255) можно написать следующее:

```py
from math import sqrt

def get_xy(i):
    d = int(sqrt(1 + (i - 1) * 8) + 1) // 2 - 1
    r = i - d * (d + 1) // 2 - 1
    return (r, d - r) if d & 1 else (d - r, r)

i = 44444444447777777777777
p = get_xy(i)
print(i, p)
```

Вывод:

```
44444444447777777777777 (103664287789, 194478109221)
```

Answer (score 3):

Кажется, у меня есть решение, вот код на питоне:

```
num = int(input())
sum = 1
i = 1
while (num>sum):
    i += 1
    sum += i
diff = sum - num
if (i%2):
    Y = i - diff
    X = diff + 1
else:
    Y = diff + 1
    X = i - diff
```

Таковым образом мы вычисляем номер диагонали, на которой лежит число (а это полезно, ведь на диагоналях соседние числа отличаются на единицу). Это возможно благодаря тому, что на каждой диагонали лежит на 1 число больше, чем на предыдущей.

Далее, мы смотрим на чётность номера диагонали. По совместительству это количество чисел на диагонали, и простейшим образом вычисляем позицию числа в матрице. Можно поэкспериментировать.

Comment: 1) `sum` - плохое название для переменной, оно перекрывает встроенную функцию, 2) в условиях для `while` и `if` круглые скобки в питоне не нужны, 3) переменные лучше называть с маленькой буквы - это я про `X` и `Y`, большие буквы - для классов (и иногда ещё для матриц, но не для скаляров/векторов)